# Catching exceptions by reference

Tags: c++, exception, reference

In [this C++ tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/), in the section titled "Standard exceptions", there is this example code which uses a class derived from the standard exception class in the STL:

```
// standard exceptions
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;

class myexception: public exception
{
  virtual const char* what() const throw()
  {
    return "My exception happened";
  }
} myex; //Declares an instance of myexception outside of the main function

int main () {
  try
  {
    throw myex;
  }
  catch (exception& e) //My question is regarding this line of code
  {
    cout << e.what() << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

That code prints out `My exception happened`. However, if I remove the ampersand, it prints out `std::exception`, which is what happens when you call `what()` with the standard exception class, not the derived class.

The website gives this explanation:

> We have placed a handler that catches exception objects by reference
>   (notice the ampersand & after the type), therefore this catches also
>   classes derived from exception, like our myex object of class
>   myexception.

Is throwing `myex` kind of like "calling a the `catch` function, and passing `myex` as a parameter"? Because it that case, I would imagine that it doesn't matter whether you throw the exception by value or by reference (that's what the ampersand does right?), because you are still throwing a `myexception` rather than an `exception`. And due to dynamic binding and polymorphism or something like that, `e.what()` should still print out `My exception happened` rather than `std::exception`.

Comment: It's pretty straightforward. If you catch by value of base type a derived object will be sliced. If you catch by reference you get a base reference to the derived object, so polymorphic functions will be called from derived class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is happening due to object slicing.

If you assign an object of a derived class to an instance of a base class (as in the case of using a copy c'tor when passing by value) all the information of the derived class will be lost (sliced).

For example,

```
class Base {
   int baseInfo;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
   int someInfo;
};
```

Then if you were to write this:

```
Derived myDerivedInstance;

Base baseInstance = myDerivedInstance;
```

Then the "someInfo" in `myDerivedInstance` is sliced away in `baseInstance`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Didn't know about object slicing but now I do. cplusplus.com's tutorials seem really lacking sometimes, but I guess that's what I should expect for reading such short tutorials instead of a real book.

Answer (score 3):

You can kind of think of it like that, but (like a function call), the exception is passed by value to the `catch` handler.  Since it's passed by value, it's copied to a `std::exception` local to the `catch` handler.  It does that with `std::exception`s copy constructor, in which case the copy no longer has any private data held by a `myexception`, nor the derived functions.  Functions do the exact same thing.  This is called "object slicing", and is why you never store virtual base types by value, only by pointer or reference. You'd see the same behavior with a `std::vector<std::exception>`.  Contained elements would lose all derived data.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, you can use copy-semantics or reference-semantics when passing and catching objects, copying being the default inherited from C. When you use copy-semantics, the program just constructs an **exception** object from **myexception**. Since **exception** knows nothing about its descendents, you lose the specific parts of the **myexception** object.

That's why you must always use references or pointers when you need polymorphism.

Comment: Thanks for clearing things up, especially with your final comment.