# exception passed by value

Tags: c++, exception

When I write my `try/catch` blocks I always throw objects by value and catch by reference. I also apply the rule that the most derived classes must come first.

Today I tried to catch BY VALUE violating this main rule. The code below executes without any problem and prints `"A4"`.

Question: what type of `CCA` argument is passed to the exception handler that executes? The original object thrown is `CCB` passed by value to a `CCA` object: is this an example of memory slicing problem or somekind of corruption i.e. the object `CCA` cannot be totally trusted?

Regards

AFG

```
  class CCA{
        int m_value;
  public:
        CCA( int value ) : m_value( value ){}            
  };

  class CCB : public CCA{
  public: 
        CCB( int value ): CCA( value ){}
  };


  main(){     
        try{
              throw CCB(4);
        }catch( CCA a ){
              std::cout << " A:" << a.value() << std::endl; 
              // this is the catch clause that executes
        }catch( CCB b ){
           std::cout << " B:" << b.value() << std::endl;
        }     
 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Catching exceptions by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350526/catching-exceptions-by-reference)

Comment: Sliced objects might still appear to work if the derived class doesn't add any data members or virtual functions to the base. That doesn't mean it wasn't sliced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is **slicing**: The inability of the base copy constructor to discriminate an argument of the genuinely same type from one of a derived class type:

```
struct Base {
  Base(Base const &);  // must accept any derived class
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Catch block for exception is always selected in order then it presented in the code. So if you reverse the order of exceptions you program printed you `B:4`

In your code the first catch clause has been selected and copy-constructor for base class passed the copy instance of original but It's will be a real base class instance.

The usual solution to provide catch blocs in closest-first order and pass parameters by reference.