# Boost program_options exception not replacing %canonical_option% tag

Tags: c++, exception, boost

Have been integrating this (version 1.52.0) into my app, but have stumbled upon the problem as described above.

In the example attached the exception what() method always still has the %canonical_option% tag intact and is not replaced with my option name.

I'm using VS2008, have disabled unicode (option 'none') and removed all other files from my project, it's only this code in a main.cpp file.

Or have I got this all wrong and there is something else I should be calling to format the exception message with the correct parameter name?

```
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>

namespace po = boost::program_options;

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    try {

        po::options_description optionalParams("optional");

        optionalParams.add_options() 
            ("log_severity,l", po::value<int>()->required(), "Minimum severity logging level")
            ("log_file,g", po::value<string>(), "Full path to log file")
            ;

        po::variables_map optMap;

        po::parsed_options parsed = po::command_line_parser(argc, argv)
            .options(optionalParams)
            .allow_unregistered()
            .run();

        po::store(parsed, optMap);

        po::notify(optMap);

    }
    catch(po::error e)
    {
        cout << e.what();
        return 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When I look at the code again, after having a proper browse through the boost code, the answer becomes more obvious.

```
catch(po::error e)
{
    cout << e.what();
    return 0;
}
```

Should be

```
catch(po::error& e)
{
    cout << e.what();
    return 0;
}
```

Without the reference, we get 'object slicing' which is explained well here:

[Catching exceptions by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350526/catching-exceptions-by-reference?rq=1)

Not using the reference means we lose the overridden 'what' method which does the template replacement.

Comment: lol - I was way too bound up in the detail to see this - :) glad you got it sorted

Answer (score 3):

I just spent an hour debugging this - it's an interesting behavior actually - the only issue with your code I think is the fact that you are catching `po::error`

```
catch(po::error e)
{
   cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If you change the catch to be the line above to this

```
catch(po::required_option e)
{
   cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

you get the following out as an error message.

```
the option '--log_severity' is required but missing
Press any key to continue . . .
```

So basically it looks like the substitution only gets done in the derived exceptions.

### Edit:

After some reading you can actually catch a `std::exception` and it will print out the correct message when you call `what()`. See link below for all the details.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/exception/doc/boost-exception.html

I also discovered that there is a method that can be used to aid you in diagnosing what is happening when the exception is thrown:

```
#include <boost/exception/diagnostic_information.hpp>

...

catch(...)
{
    std::cerr << "Unhandled exception!" << std::endl <<
    boost::current_exception_diagnostic_information();
    return 0;
}
```

Change the program as above for example and it prints out something like below:

```
Unhandled exception!
Throw location unknown (consider using BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION)
Dynamic exception type: class boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<struct    
                               boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<class 
                               boost::program_options::required_option> >
std::exception::what: the option '--log_severity' is required but missing
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Though not finding the root cause of the problem your work got me into the code proper which revealed the true cause.  Kudos and thanks :)